# How do I prevent my callable Lua table passing itself as an argument to __call?

Tags: lua, callable, metatable

Say I have the following code:

```
local t = {};
setmetatable(t, {__call=print});
t(3, 5, 7)
```

Instead of printing:

```
3    5    7
```

it prints:

```
table: 0x9357020    3   5   7
```

The id of the table is that of `t`.

How can I make it behave as though I called `print` directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't; the function specified by `__call` always gets passed the item that was called.

What you could do, though, is create a wrapper function that just discards the first argument and calls the function you originally wanted to call with just the arguments after the first, and set that wrapper function as the `__call` value.

Comment: I suspected that would be the case.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You cant, but you can use this code:

```
local t = {};
setmetatable(t, {__call=function(t,...)print(...)});
t(3, 5, 7)
```

Prints 3 ,5, 7
`

Comment: You could also use `return print` to take advantage of tail recursion.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming this will perform better than `table.remove(arg, 1)`?  It seems like it should, but I'm not familiar enough with Lua internals.

Comment: @JasonFruit much so yes. consider that the arg table would have to be built, and all elements moved down.